# image with pop up image Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: popup, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

**I changed to use modals.**

I changed this website to BS4 beta. on [this page](http://www.pscompetitiveedge.com/references.html) when you click on an image, it should open a pop up or modal with an image.

```html
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
       <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/bluewater.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/bluewater.jpg" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Bluewater Resort &amp; Casino"></a> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/semhardrock.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/hardrock.gif" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Hard Rock Hotel &amp; Casino" ></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/trump.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/trump29.jpg" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Trump 29 Casino"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/bestwestern.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/bestwestern.gif" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Best Western"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
       <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/delsol.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/delsol.jpg" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Casino Del Sol"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="javascript:popUp('ltrs/ag.htm')"><img src="photos/logo/ag.jpg" class="thumbnail img-fluid" alt="Apache Gold Resort Casino"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the BS .js listed at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? This used to work when it was Bootstrap 3.

Comment: what does the autoplay sound have to do with it? I just posted that warning here for anyone if they went to the site and didn't want sound  coming on

Comment: there is no more autoplay sound

Answer (score 1):

It seems your method *popup* isn't available in the global scope.

See the error from my console : 
[image: error console]

I have this error when I click on items for example Roswell Toyota.

Plus you have an error on this script :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit-button").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

       // you would need to set the following values from your form fields
       var name = $("#form_name").val();
       var email = $("#form_email").val();
       var phone = $("#form_phone").val();
       var message = $("#form_message").val();
       var dataString = 'surname='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "contact.php",
         data: dataString,
         success: function() {
           $(".messages").html("Thank you for contacting me.  I will be in touch soon.").css("visibility", "visible");
           $("#submit-button").trigger("reset")
         $('.messages').fadeTo( "slow", 1 ).fadeTo(3000, 0);
        }
      });
    });
```

You should add at the ")};"

Comment: that script is gone now

Comment: Strange I found that yesterday.
Did it help you on your *popUp* issue ?

Comment: No :( I decided to change it from popups to modal windows. It was an old site for a close friend of mine. I told him it needs to be changed to modern coding. Hopefully I will finish the page today. I will post again if I am stuck, Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my friend, there is tiny error of semicolon.....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit-button").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

// you would need to set the following values from your form fields
var name = $("#form_name").val();
var email = $("#form_email").val();
var phone = $("#form_phone").val();
var message = $("#form_message").val();
var dataString = 'surname='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contact.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $(".messages").html("Thank you for contacting me.  I will be in touch soon.").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#submit-button").trigger("reset")
    $('.messages').fadeTo( "slow", 1 ).fadeTo(3000, 0);
  }
});
```

});

See on second last line after `trigger("reset");`

and Please add the BS4 js straight after jquery it is good practice to do and it can cause unexpected errors...